# Using one-way hash functions as the encryption method

Tags: hash, hmac, classical-cipher, post-quantum-cryptography, one-way-function

Suppose two parties want to communicate securely with each other (Bob and Alice) using a simple messaging system in English. There are approximately [180,000 currently used](http://oxforddictionaries.com/words/how-many-words-are-there-in-the-english-language) words in the English language.

## The protocol

1. Bob creates a random private key of 512 bits in length e.g. `2fba5541fda58c643524cb629cb310674d029d7dd688e974f9c0d95299c228fa3531d06a29a69b6715ad4ec074d2bb50393fe5b4e7d2de5bc83b10ac7d3114ff`
2. Bob also chooses a random hash function from a group of hash functions that all output 512 bits. These could be SHA-2, Keccak, Grøstl, BLAKE, JH, Whirlpool and Skein hash functions.
3. Bob gives the key and chosen hashing method to Alice (either in person or using some other key exchange method).
4. Using a program and the dictionary of 180,000 words, Bob and Alice compute HMAC(key, word) for each word in the dictionary using the chosen hash function. Each person calculates this on their machine.
5. The values are stored in a lookup table with columns (id, word, hmac) in an indexed database on each person's machine. With a HMAC generation time of 23 milliseconds per word on a single core (reference machine: Core i5 @2.67GHz), this would take 69 minutes to construct a database of values given 180,000 words. Using all 4 cores, splitting up the work and using multithreaded programming this could be dropped to 17 minutes to generate the full database on each machine. This is a one-time generation, so no big deal.
6. Bob writes message to Alice.
7. For encryption, the program selects each plaintext word in the message, then looks up the corresponding HMAC hash value in the database then replaces the plaintext word with that hash value. A database lookup for each word and corresponding hash will be very fast in a modern, indexed database.
8. The hashes for each word are concatenated together so it is one full string of unintelligible text. This makes up the ciphertext.
9. A message authentication code is computed on the text using HMAC(key, ciphertext) and sent with the message e.g. ciphertext || MAC (concatenated).
10. Alice receives the encrypted message. Grabs the last 512 bits of the message which is the MAC. Then validates the MAC with her copy of the key and the hash algorithm using HMAC(key, ciphertext). Incorrect MACs mean the message is discarded immediately.
11. Alice's program breaks up the message into the hashed words as it knows each word was hashed into a fixed length 512 bit hash.
12. Alice's program looks up each hashed word in her database's dictionary of words to retrieve the corresponding plaintext word. The program assembles the message back to plaintext for her. This database lookup for each word and corresponding hash should also be very fast in a modern, indexed database.

## Security features:

- The strength of the protocol relies on the difficulty in computing a
  pre-image of the HMAC hash of one of the hashed words to find the key. This
  would be 2<sup>512</sup> for a standard computer using a brute force
  search or 2<sup>256</sup> using Grover's algorithm.
- There is also security in that the attacker does not know which hash
  function that was used by either party. They will have to try brute forcing using all available 512 bit hash algorithms.
- All hashed words compute to the same length output e.g. 512 bit. This means shorter length words are indistinguishable from longer ones.
- If the hashed output and MAC are concatenated as a single string and sent, then the output is indistinguishable from a random string.

## Potential disadvantages:

- Frequency analysis of the output might help determine simple words in the ciphertext such as 'the' etc if that word is repeated and sent multiple times. This isn't necessarily a problem as it's only a simple word and doesn't convey much meaning to the message. You can also avoid that by not using simple words at all in the message.
- The message doesn't account for numbers or punctuation. Solution would be to send simple messages such as 'LEAVE MIDNIGHT' then any further sentences could be sent in another message. Also numbers could be expanded to their word equivalent e.g. '2' becomes 'TWO'.
- The time to generate the dictionary of words/hashes can be time consuming. As mentioned it may only take 17 minutes using a fast computer and multithreaded program to create the dictionary on each computer. With a Core i7 or ever increasing speeds of computers it would be even faster. From there the same dictionary could be transferred to any other devices needing to communicate.
- The encrypted output is much longer than the message itself. Not really a big deal considering today's networking and storage capabilities.
- Assuming an attacker knew the protocol, they may be able to discern how many words were in the message based on the length of the ciphertext. This could be fixed by using padding words, and setting a fixed length message size.

## Feedback

Now I would appreciate some constructive feedback.

- Are there any similar encryption systems currently in use?
- What else could go wrong with the protocol?
- What are some more downsides and mitigations?
- What are some improvements that could be made?

## Updates after feedback

After feedback regarding the scheme it is vulnerable to chosen-plaintext attack and frequency analysis of past messages unless each word is only ever used once. This is not particularly usable so I devised some changes.

A random nonce/IV is created for each message. This will be 512 bits and sent with the message. To encrypt, Bob computes HMAC(key, nonce || word) for each word in the message. || indicates concatenation. Encryption will be very fast and a lookup dictionary is no longer needed as it will change each message.

For decryption, Alice constructs a temporary dictionary using HMAC(key, nonce || word) for each word in the dictionary. Alice's program looks up each hashed word in her database's dictionary of words to retrieve the corresponding plaintext word. The program then reassembles the plaintext message.

Only disadvantage is that the decryption of each message will be slower. This could be made faster by using more powerful hardware, e.g. faster, more modern CPUs or multi-cpu/multi-core server system and splitting up the work for each core. Decryption time decreases with more powerful hardware. The scheme still maintains security in that it is very difficult (2<sup>512</sup>) for an attacker to find a pre-image and retrieve the original key especially when they don't know the exact hash algorithm that is being used. This would be ideal for organisations with dedicated hardware for sending and receiving messages.

For modern PCs at the moment it may be possible to reduce the output size of the hash algorithms e.g. 256 bit to decrease the decryption time for each message, while still maintaining a good security margin. Quantum cryptography would reduce that to 2<sup>128</sup> to find a pre-image however which is still a long time even for an attacker with supercomputers. I would not lower the hash size below that.

Comment: Frequency analysis is much more effective for this than you think it is. A competent attacker would probably figure out your protocol from only a handful of messages, and start building a unique block database. This system is millions of times slower than standard methods, and millions of times less secure, making it trillions of times less desirable, in addition to being extremely inflexible to input data. Do not pursue.

Comment: Can you explain how frequency analysis is more effective than I think it is? I specifically mentioned it could be avoided by *not* using common words like `the` in messages. How does building a unique block database help them figure out which word corresponds to which hash with absolute certainty? They would have to brute force attempt it at cost of 2^512 or construct a rainbow table. I agree it is a lot slower than conventional methods, but it's short messages so it's not a huge deal. Please quantify your hyperbole that it is "millions of times less secure" than other methods.

Comment: The final meaning is what is important, if you use "JGK" instead of "THE", a long term analysis of ALL of your messages will tell an attacker the meaning of the message is "THE". No rainbow tables required, just a simple 2D array of your hashes, the frequency, the guessed meaning, and correlations to other hashes. Known plaintext and chosen ciphertext attacks also destroy the scheme with near 0 workload. Never assume an attacker cannot use those, or is not extremely intelligent with substantial resources.

Comment: Usually frequency analysis is usually done on individual letters rather than on words. If I use [this page](http://www.wordfrequency.info/) as a reference you can see the common words and their ranking. Basically it becomes a probability game for an attacker. Did they use the word `the` or `and` or `of` etc. Other common words are very likely to match that hash too. An attacker can't tell which word with absolute certainty. Please also explain the usefulness of decrypting the word `the`. You say "long term analysis" of all messages. How long is that? Why not re-exchange keys every other month?

Comment: Can you quantify how "'known plaintext' and 'chosen ciphertext attacks' also destroy the scheme with near 0 workload"?

Comment: Frequency analysis can be done on anything, from individual bits to entire messages. I should have said chosen plaintext: The attacker gets one party to encrypt a chapter of a book for example, determines the scheme by trial and error, then can decrypt many messages without the key. Your scheme does not rely on the strength of the key or the hash length at all (except for authentication), it is simply a substitution codebook with a fixed length output. Known plaintext will reveal the use of the same words in all other messages with the same key.

Comment: Can you explain how an attacker will coerce a user to encrypt "a chapter of a book" or other chosen plaintext? They can't communicate with the user outside the channel. If they attempt to forge/alter a message asking the other user to send a chapter from the book, then the MAC will fail. They also can't send a valid message to the other user because they don't have the key. For all an attacker knows, the users could be sending military style messages e.g. "ATTACK BEGINS MIDNIGHT" or "LEAVE BASE MIDDAY". There could be no common/frequent words to assist an attacker with frequency analysis.

Comment: For chosen plaintext attacks this is pretty much broken: Any word chosen in the beginning can be detected afterwards. But also known plaintext attacks work against this with quite well: If I know plaintext/ciphertext pairs of a longer text, most messages will be easy to reconstruct. And ever since the Enigma cipher, known plaintext attacks are a real threat. This scheme is only secure against "ciphertext only" attacks, but it has been decades since this was considered secure.

Comment: You do not need to know how an attacker can do the things they do, always assume they can. That was just an example of how it could almost completely reveal the plaintexts for numerous messages. 
There could be no common words for frequency analysis, but there probably will be. "NOW IS THE ____ OF OUR ____"; those are common words, the less common are unknown, but im sure someone here can figure them out in seconds. Even if you change keys, prior texts can reveal writing styles and the types of information discussed, making future messages easier to crack

Comment: Perhaps a unique IV could be sent with each message. Then that is used in creating the hash for each word. This would involve recomputing the database for each message though. Depending on computer/server  speed/capability this may be OK. With a multi CPU/multi core server this would be done in a minute or less. Ilmari Karonen [posted a modification](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10156/8220) below which could work too.

Comment: You may want to improve your statement: "There is also security in that the attacker does not know which hash function that was used by either party." Making things harder like this for the attacker does not increase security.  True, in many contexts it is desirable to make things more difficult for the aggressor--in military operations, for example--but we cannot conflate this with security.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your scheme would make a nice puzzle for amateur codebreakers.  That's about the best that can be said for it.

It does *not* meet the generally accepted standards for a modern encryption scheme; in particular, it is not [semantically secure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security).  In fact, the security of your scheme would be seriously compromised if an attacker obtained even a small amount of [known plaintext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Known-plaintext_attack), and, if used to encrypt sufficient amounts of text, it could even be vulnerable to [ciphertext-only attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext-only_attack) using frequency and correlation analysis.

In particular, note that one of your claimed "security features" does *not* hold: if the plaintext contains *any* repeated words, the resulting ciphertext can be easily distinguished from a random string by the presence of repeated 512-bit blocks (which, in a truly random string, would be astronomically unlikely).

---

That said, if you really want a secure word-by-word encryption scheme using HMAC, here's a variation of your scheme that would work:

- Bob and Alice choose a 512-bit hash function.  This choice can be public, so let's just pick [SHA-512](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-512) and be done with it.
- Bob and Alice somehow arrange to share a secret key *K*<sub>1</sub>.  The key can have any size, as long as it's long enough to resist brute force guessing attempts; 128 bits or more should be fine.

  Bob and Alice also both modify *K*<sub>1</sub> in some agreed-upon way to obtain a second shared key *K*<sub>2</sub> ≠ *K*<sub>1</sub>.  The modification can be completely trivial, such as flipping the first bit in the key; we just need the two keys to be different; see below for the reason.  (For [technical reasons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash-based_message_authentication_code#Definition_.28from_RFC_2104.29), however, appending a null byte or hashing *K*<sub>1</sub> to obtain *K*<sub>2</sub> should be avoided.  Pretty much any other method is OK.)
- To send a message to Alice, Bob splits the message into words (of no more than 64 bytes = 512 bits each).

  Optionally, Bob also chooses a ["nonce"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce) word or phrase and appends it to the message.  This nonce word could be random, or it could just be e.g. a message number.  It's also a good idea for Bob to include a timestamp and a channel designator (e.g. "from Bob to Alice") in the message to guard against [replay attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack); if unique, these can serve as the nonce.

  First, Bob computes the HMAC of the entire message (as it would look when decrypted by Alice, including the nonce, if any) using the chosen hash function and the shared key *K*<sub>1</sub>.  This will form the first 64 bytes of the ciphertext.

  To encrypt each word of the message, Bob computes the HMAC of the previous 64 bytes of the ciphertext using the key *K*<sub>2</sub>, XORs the word to be encrypted (padded e.g. with nulls to 64 bytes) with the HMAC output, and appends the resulting 64-byte string to the ciphertext.
- To decrypt the first word of the message, Alice takes the first 64 bytes of the ciphertext, computes the HMAC of them (using the key *K*<sub>2</sub>) and XORs the result with the next 64 bytes of the ciphertext.  Then she repeats the process for all subsequent pairs of 64-byte blocks to decrypt the rest of the message.

  Finally, Alice computes the HMAC of the entire decrypted message using the key *K*<sub>1</sub> and compares it with the first 64 bytes of the ciphertext.  If they match, she'll know that the message is from Bob (or someone else who knows the key) and hasn't been tampered with.

This scheme has a number of advantages compared to yours:

- It doesn't need a database.
- It can handle arbitrary words (except for the 64 byte length limit, which shouldn't be an issue in practice), even if they're not found in any dictionary.
- It can also handle punctuation, e.g. by treating it as a separate word, or by appending it to the preceding word.
- If each message includes a unique nonce, it's [IND-CCA2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IND-CCA2) secure, i.e. it meets the highest security requirements expected of a modern encryption scheme.
- Even if nonces are not used (or are accidentally reused), IND-CCA2 security is only compromised to the extent that an attacker may learn if the same message is sent twice.

---

Ps. A careful reader may note that the requirement that Bob split them message into "words" in order to encrypt it is somewhat superfluous: it would be much easier for Bob to just split his message into 64-byte blocks.

This also saves Bob from having to worry about padding the blocks up to 64 bytes, except possibly for the last block.  For the last block, instead of padding the plaintext, Bob can (if he doesn't mind divulging the exact length of the plaintext) just truncate the HMAC output to the length of the last plaintext block.

With those modifications, the scheme I've described above is essentially a simplified version of [SIV mode](http://www.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/siv.pdf), except built on HMAC and CFB mode instead of CMAC and CTR mode, and using HMAC also as a replacement for the block cipher for encryption.  All these modifications should be safe, although they rely heavily on the security properties of HMAC (in particular, on HMAC-SHA512 being a [PRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudorandom_function_family)).  The nice thing about SIV mode is that it's "maximally misuse-resistant"; it's really hard to make its security fail catastrophically, no matter what you do.

**Correction:** The protocol as I originally suggested it would've been vulnerable to a serious [chosen-plaintext attack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chosen-plaintext_attack) if used without a nonce: if Eve could trick Alice or Bob to encrypt a message of her choice, she could submit any 64-byte block from an earlier ciphertext as the message in order to learn its HMAC, and thus learn the corresponding word in the earlier message.  I've modified the protocol to use different HMAC keys for the authentication and encryption parts, which should plug this hole.  The moral of the story being, be careful about key reuse!

Comment: In the encryption step, are you saying that for the second word, you would HMAC the previous 128 bytes of the ciphertext which provides the key for the next word to be XORed? I would leave the original key at 512 bits or even 1024 bits though as it doesn't make any sense to weaken it. Also I wouldn't communicate which hash algorithm was being used in public. That would also weaken the scheme. But SHA-512 is fine for the example.

Comment: For each word, I suggested HMACing the previous 16 bytes (i.e. 512 bits) of the ciphertext (i.e. the part of the ciphertext encoding the previous word). You _could_ HMAC more of the preceding ciphertext, but there's no real advantage to it. As for the hash and the key length, hiding the choice of the hash only adds at most a few bits of strength. That hardly makes up for the fact that it makes the security of your scheme harder to study. And you _can_ use a longer key if you want, but 128 bits is enough to thwart any plausible brute force attacks using computers based on known physics.

Comment: If including just the previous 512 bits, is that really enough new entropy for the next key? The only difference is words and null padding. How did you calculate that multiple algorithms only adds minimal strength? There would be a 1 in 7 chance of success. Best case, an attacker guesses the right algorithm and needs to perform 2^512 brute force calculations. Worst case they need to try 2^512 + 2^512 ... This is worse if you only have a 128 bit key. Then they only need to try 2^128 calculations to find the right key. On a quantum computer this would reduced to 2^64 using Grover's algorithm.

Comment: In your modified edition, if you need two keys now, why doesn't Bob send both keys to Alice at the start? Also why not HMAC the entire encrypted message for the authentication with key #1 (ie "Encrypt then MAC") which has better security. Can key #2 be re-used for other messages safely?

Comment: Bob _could_ send both two separate keys to Alice, but generally, secure key distribution is the hard part of symmetric-key encryption. If Bob can send, say, 1024 key bits to Alice, they're better off using it all as $K_1$, and deriving $K_2$ from it as I suggested, than they'd be splitting it into two 512-bit keys. As for key reuse, yes, both keys can be reused for multiple messages. The important part in the modified scheme is that $K_1$ is only used to HMAC plaintext, while $K_2$ is only user to HMAC ciphertext. That's why two keys are needed.

Comment: As for your other questions above: 1) SHA-512 only has 512 bits of internal state, so it can't store more entropy than that anyway. Up to that limit, the last 512 bits of the ciphertext should contain all the entropy in the key and message put together, so you don't really need any more. 2) If you increase the attacker's workload by a factor of 8 (he has to try up to 8 hashes to find the right one), that's equivalent to 3 bits of extra strength ($2^3 = 8$). 3) Yes, encrypt-then-MAC _is_ generally better, but the "SIV trick" (using the MAC of the plaintext as an IV) wouldn't work with it.

Comment: I've marked yours as the accepted answer because you provided some constructive criticism and actually came up with a workable solution using the HMAC. Whereas the others just criticize with an arrogant attitude and don't bother to offer up ideas for improvement. So thank you.

Comment: One thing I would like to add is that for SHA to function as a PRF apparently you need to input twice as much entropy into it, then you get 512 bits of entropy output which is considered to have full entropy. This is mentioned in [NIST Special Publication 800-90B (draft)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_extractor). So perhaps inputting more of the previous hash outputs into the next key to XOR with the next word will provide a better quality random key. What do you think?

Answer (score 7):

This is highly insecure, for the same reason that ECB mode and simple substitution ciphers are.  Every time you use the word `the` in your message, it will be encrypted the same way.  The same goes for other, lower-frequency (but still fairly common) words -- like `as` or `with` or `will` (or any of hundreds of other examples).

This is a humongous clue to cryptanalysts.  For instance, if we know that one word is `will`, then it's likely that the next word is a verb.  If we know that another word is `because`, then that gives us some information about the sentence structure.  Word frequency analysis might reveal a lot of words, and then the pairing and location of known words might give us some clue about what is being said or about what nearby words might be -- and each clue that lets us deduce some additional information will give us additional clues that can be used to deduce still more, and so on.

And, of course, this scheme is completely insecure against known-plaintext attacks.  If I know a few of the messages that were sent, I learn the decoding of all of the words in those messages, and that may help me recover parts of other messages.  This vulnerability is considered unacceptable for a modern cryptographic scheme; similar sorts of vulnerabilities have been exploited in the past to break other cryptosystems in practice.

A hint: You generally don't want to try to design your own scheme.  Cryptographers have spent a lot of mental energy trying to design good schemes;
it's unlikely that whatever you come up with will be better than the best that the entire field was able to do.  Instead, stick to standard constructions -- in this case, use authenticated encryption, and save your mental energy for other pursuits.

Comment: Sure the word `the` might be encrypted the same way, but I specifically mentioned it should be avoided using common words like that in messages. Even if this is a big clue to cryptanalysts as you say, how does it *help* them decipher the message? If an attacker decrypted the word `the` it is not that useful to understanding the remaining content or intent of message. All other words may have more or less the same chance of occurring. This doesn't help an attacker given they know nothing about the length of each word either seeing all encrypted words are the same length.

Comment: "If an attacker decrypted the word the it is not that useful to understanding the remaining content or intent of message." Actually, that is how the allies cracked the German Enigma code during WW2. That and knowing the scheme, which they partially reverse engineered.

Comment: They cracked the Enigma code because they got a hold of an Enigma machine. Also their randomness produced by operators was insufficient, there were procedural flaws, operator mistakes, laziness, neglect of the need to introduce systematic changes of encoding parameters, crib-dragging and capturing of key tables and hardware. That's how Allied cryptanalysts were able to be so successful.

Comment: @jj57: Having an Enigma machine just tells you how the scheme works, not what key was used to encrypt a given message. A modern, secure encryption scheme would not have been affected in any way by an attacker obtaining an encryption device, or even a detailed schematic of one. See [Kerckhoffs' principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerckhoffs%27s_principle) for details.

Comment: "the" would be an example of a crib. It allows you to derive the meaning of part of the plaintext. Weather reports almost always started with the same thing, and that allowed derival of the key knowing the scheme. In this scheme, cribs are way more effective, since Enigma encrypted words differently within the message.

Answer (score 5):

> "Frequency analysis of the output might help determine simple words in
>   the ciphertext such as 'the' etc if that word is repeated and sent
>   multiple times. This isn't necessarily a problem as it's only a simple
>   word and doesn't convey much meaning to the message".

If the word "the" doesn't convey much meaning, then why have you used that particular word 59 times in your question? The answer is simple - because it *is* important and it *does* convey meaning.  It's a basic linguistic structure.  Saying it's not important is like a programmer saying that curly braces, semi-colons, and brackets are not important (depending on the syntax of the language) simply because they appear frequently.

Having to avoid the word "the" is highly suggestive of your protocol/system being weak.

Comment: +1 for the last sentence. If your encryption scheme can't encrypt regular English without leaking an insane amount of information, then I think it's probably not too worth considering...

Answer (score 4):

This is a type of code book security. Code books can be very strong or very weak depending on operational security.

If you never reuse a code book word *even in a single message* and the code words are genuinely random - this approach could work.

Of course if you can't reuse code words and need perhaps 40 instances of THE and 30 instances BE to avoid running out of them in a conversation, the database will be larger and less convenient than sharing a generous one-time-pad when Alice and Bob first met.

Incidentally, Windwalkers are somewhat different as their language isn't Germanic and the required frequency analysis would be unorthodox. For "hash languages" I suggest choosing an uncommon language of non-Germanic non-Romantic origin that no one has compiled a frequency table for. Perhaps Tolkien Elvish?

Comment: While I understand what you're pointing at, I can't help posting this [tongue-in-cheek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tongue-in-cheek) comment saying that it would be dangerous to use such languages too. While some crypto-freaks out there actually speak "Tolkien's Elvish", others have (at least) thrown some analytics towards such languages. I know I did about 3 years ago, finding out that Elvish has letter-frequency problems just like every other language. Same applies to Star Trek's Klingon too btw. ;)

Comment: Yes that was the intention originally, not reusing words. However perhaps a unique IV could be sent with each message. Then that is used in creating the hash for each word. This would involve recomputing the database for each message though. Depending on computer/server speed/capability this may be OK. With a multi CPU/multi core server this would be done in a under a minute. Ilmari Karonen [posted a modification]( http://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10156/8220) which could work too.

Answer (score 2):

This scheme is very unsecure.

In my humble opinion is like a complicated "translate your message into a unknown language".

In my opinion it looks like an hashed version of the Windtalkers (WW2 native americans language used to encrypt messages).
Your version add one more level: you have few languages (hash functions) to choose among.

Comment: Except that each key and algorithm will produce an entirely different unknown language each time. If you had just one key and one language then over time you could map the words from one language to the next.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But it is still not secure. It is not IND as a start (try to encrypt a message $m_1 = A A A A A$ and a $m_2 = A B C D E$ [every single letter is a single word]).

Comment: It is not completely different every time, the words change but the syntax stays the same.